# Set is nowhere dense iff and only if it is contained in closure of complement of closure.

Tags: general-topology

A set $A\subseteq X$ is said to be nowhere dense if $\operatorname{Int}\left(\overline{A}\right)=\emptyset$, where the bar denotes closure.

I want to prove that $A$ is nowhere dense if and only if $A\subseteq \overline{X\backslash \overline{A}}$.

To prove sufficiency note that if $A$ is nowhere dense,
$$\emptyset=\operatorname{Int}\left(\overline{A}\right)=X\backslash \left(\overline{X\backslash \overline{A}}\right)$$
which implies
$$\overline{X\backslash \overline{A}}=X$$ and evidently $$A\subseteq X=\overline{X\backslash \overline{A}}$$

If, on the other hand, $A\subseteq \overline{X\backslash \overline{A}}$, then
$$X\backslash \overline{\left(X\backslash\overline{A}\right)}\subseteq X\backslash \overline{A} \subseteq X\backslash A$$
thus 
$$\operatorname{Int}\overline{A}\subseteq X\backslash \overline{A} \subseteq X\backslash A$$

In order to complete the proof I would like one of the expressions on the right to be empty, but I can't see how that could happen.

And that's when I get stuck. How do I proceed? Am I barking up the wrong tree here? Is there a different and more simple approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, I'll denote the interior of a subset $E$ by $E^\circ$. Recall that $\overline{X\setminus E}=X\setminus E^\circ$ for every $E\subset X$. Then, it follows that

$$\begin{align}
A \textrm{ is nowhere dense} \quad &\Leftrightarrow \quad (\overline{A})^\circ = \varnothing \\
&\Leftrightarrow \quad X\setminus (\overline{A})^\circ = X \\
&\Leftrightarrow \quad \overline{X\setminus \overline{A}} = X 
\end{align}$$

So, the implication $(\Rightarrow)$ is already done (since $A \subset X$).

Now, let's see the other direction. By the previous observation, it is sufficient to show that 
$$A \subset \overline{X\setminus\overline A} \quad \Rightarrow \quad X=\overline{X\setminus\overline A}$$

Clearly, $\overline{X\setminus\overline A} \subset X$. Let $y\in X$. If $y\in \overline A$ then $y\in \overline{X\setminus\overline A}$ (since $A \subset \overline{X\setminus\overline A}$). If not, $y\in X\setminus\overline A$ and then $y\in \overline{X\setminus\overline A}$ (since $X\setminus\overline A \subset \overline{X\setminus\overline A}$).

In any case $y\in \overline{X\setminus\overline A}$, which means $X\subset \overline{X\setminus\overline A}$ as we want to show.

Comment: I agree, but that is not quite what I need to prove. I need to prove that $A\subseteq \overline{X\backslash  \overline{A}}$ implies $A$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But it sufficient to show that $A \subset \overline{X\setminus\overline A}$ implies $X=\overline{X\setminus\overline A}$. Let's see.

Comment: First, the inclusion $\overline{X\setminus\overline A} \subset X$ is obvious. For the other direction, let $y\in X$. If $y\in \overline A$, then $y\in \overline{X\setminus\overline A}$ (since $A \subset \overline{X\setminus\overline A}$). If not, then $y\in X\setminus\overline A$ and then $y\in \overline{X\setminus\overline A}$ (since $X\setminus\overline A \subset \overline{X\setminus\overline A}$). In any case $y\in \overline{X\setminus\overline A}$, which means, $X\subset \overline{X\setminus\overline A}$ as we want to prove.

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer with the above comment so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Sure. I hope I've helped!

Answer (score 0):

Since $\overline{X\backslash \overline{A}}$ = X - int $\bar A,$
the first part is immediate.
For the second part assume A subset X - int $\bar A.$
Since the right hand side is closed, $\bar A$ subset X - int $\bar A.$
Thus int $\bar A$ subset X - int $\bar A.$
Intersect both sides by int $\bar A$ for the final conclusion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you perhaps elaborate a bit further or format your answer?

Comment: @alonsos.  Do you need help with the first statement?